# How to configure ESLint for TypeScript with IntelliJ Ultimate?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, eslint

I am trying to configure ESLint for TypeScript with IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.2.

I don't see any options under "Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> TypeScript"

[image]

I am seeing the option only for TSLint which is deprecated. How ESLint can be configured for the (Angular) project?

Comment: `Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_activate / https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_activate

Comment: If I configure for JavaScript, this will be handled for *.js files only right? I tried this way but i didnt work.

Comment: It's all there, in the help: just type `eslint typescript` in the search box and the first link will take you to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/using-tslint-code-quality-tool.html?q=eslint%20typescript#ws_eslint_linting_typescript_files_with_eslint

Comment: upgrading to 2021.1 does the trick. thank you @LazyOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be configured in **Settings | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint**. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_activate, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/using-tslint-code-quality-tool.html#ws_eslint_linting_typescript_files_with_eslint